# Advice in how to properly maintain my UPS

Tags: ups, maintenance, battery

First of all, I hope this is the right place to ask. I have looked around and this seems to be the correct place inside SE.

I do not own a server but I use a really old [APC Smart-UPS SU1000INET](https://www.apc.com/shop/hr/en/products/APC-Smart-UPS-1000-230V/P-SU1000INET) for my PC. But hey, it works like a charm. I bought it last year for like 40€ with fairly new batteries. (I think they had a couple of months of life back then)

Now, I want to maintain it properly and I wanted to ask for advice here. I check it's status etc with Powerchute Business Edition (since it's the only version of Powershute that detects this ancient piece of technology) and everything seems right.

My main concern are [the batteries](https://www.apc.com/shop/us/en/products/APC-Replacement-Battery-Cartridge-6-with-2-Year-Warranty/P-RBC6), when should I change them? I have looked at the APC webpage and they are really expensive, like 300€ (Spain). Or can they be found much cheaper outside of the official APC webpage? Does it really pay off to replace the batteries or should I look for something different in the future? (since I only use it on my PC). If the UPS serves me for 2 years, I would still consider it a success for 40€, but maybe it is an overkill and I should go for something simpler, newer, and cheaper to maintain.

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: -Vendor rated battery life expectancy is somewhere between 3-5 years depending on “circumstances” https://www.apc.com/us/en/faqs/FA158934/ - What are your expectations of your UPS? To provide significant runtime during an outage? Or (only) to provide enough power to allow your server(s) to do a graceful shutdown in case of a power outage? Do the batteries still pass their self tests?

Comment: @Rob Only a grateful shutdown, they pass the self tests 100% of the time.

Comment: I have an APC 750XL and batteries are good for about 5 years. After 4 years the ability to maintain a PC ON is iffy. I am on my 3rd set of batteries (new Jan 1 this year).

Comment: The UPS will tell you when to change batteries.

Comment: General FYI: For computers/servers, a pure sine wave UPS is recommended _(a server must use a pure sine wave UPS)_. Simulated sine wave UPS' are fine for home theater equipment, but not recommended for computers and servers since PSUs connected to a simulated sine wave UPS often have issues due to the simulated sine wave _(more info can be found via a search engine)_. UPS batteries can also be monitored via [`upsmon`](https://networkupstools.org/docs/man/upsmon.html) _(my  TrueNAS server is configred to email a weekly `upsmon` report - [example](https://pastebin.com/TwwbGiMn))_

Comment: Thanks for the info and upsmon link @JW0914, can you confirm me that [this](https://www.upspowercom.com/PRO-Windows.jsp) is the official link? The specifications of my model say it is pure sine-wave.

Comment: @S.Dre It's a BSD/Linux program, so for Windows you'd either need to use Cygwin or WSL, however I've never went that route and it may not work as expected, especially since it looks like your UPS uses a DB-9 serial cable versus USB or an ethernet-to-USB cable _(you can get an adapter interface for the serial cable, however the question remains whether `upsmon` would be able to detect it since it would be routed through Windows and not through a supported OS with direct access to the device)_. If you have a router that can run OpenWrt, OpenWrt supports `upsmon` [package: `nut-upsmon`].

Comment: Yep, it could work maybe in wsl, but yeah, I think that I can go with the powerchute I use now, since again, I am not sure it would work with my ancient DB-9 adapter to USB (Which I already use to connect the UPS to my computer)

Comment: @S.Dre I forgot to answer your first question - I'm not sure that's the developer of `upsmon`, but I'd give it a shot